# 0xE8000007 error occurring when syncing enterprise .ipa via iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I have an app that's ready for enterprise testing, but if I build an .ipa of it to distribute, attempting to sync it gives an error in iTunes that states "The app  was not installed on the  because an unknown error occurred (0xE8000007)".

If I try to install the app via Xcode organizer, I get an error that says the argument is invalid and nothing happens. I've tried multiple devices and the same thing happens.

What makes the whole thing even more strange is that if I do a build for archiving and snag the .app out of my derived data, it works fine. I also tried grabbing the .app out of the build .ipa and using that, but it gave the same error as the .ipa.

Is anyone familiar with this situation? From what I've seen it seems like it might be some kind of symlink issue, but I don't understand how that could happen if it works using the .app from build for archiving.

(The code signing and entitlements are set correctly as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally sorted this out.

I have a script that runs via the run script in build phases that copies in some derived data (namely other bundles). Turns out when archiving these bundles appear elsewhere creating a broken link. App still would build though and then iTunes wouldn't know what is going on.

Anyway, broken symlink is what was my problem...hopefully it helps someone else.

Comment: This was exactly my same issue. Did you end up fixing your script?

Comment: Yeah. I had to put in a check for which type of configuration, then for 'Release' type configurations I had to use ${PROJECT_TEMP_DIR}/../UninstalledProducts/<Bundle name> instead of ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/<Bundle name>.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've come up with using Stekenborg's input:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]; then
    echo "Copying for Release"
    cp -Rfv "${PROJECT_TEMP_DIR}/../UninstalledProducts/"*.bundle "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/"
else
    echo "Copying for Debug"
    cp -Rfv "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/"*.bundle "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/"
fi
```